# Android: How to demo automatic killing of a process

Tags: android

I want to observe an app's process being killed automatically (when the app's activity is stopped and other processes need the memory). I'm keeping my eye on Android Studio's Devices pane while I launch other processes, but this doesn't seem to kill my dormant activity. Is there a way to insure that this happens (and is observable)? (I know, . . . Why would I ever want to do this? It's because I'm teaching Android and I want to illustrate this concept.)

Comment: there are a few options in the developer settings on the device (don't keep activities, limite bg processes). You can also swipe out the app from the recent apps. It kind of kills it.

Comment: In DDMS, you can select your process and kill it yourself.  I'm not sure if this is equivalent to a process-kill initiated by the Android system however.

Comment: Doesn't Android automatically kill processes (or at least remove a process from memory) when it thinks that doing so is advantageous for the actively running apps? That's what I want to demonstrate (without killing a process myself and without artificially changing the OS settings). I've tried pressing Home to make an app no longer be active, and then starting up several other apps. But, keeping my eye on the Devices panel, I don't see my original app going away.